# instalar plugins netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ejb

Necesito realizar un proyecto con EJB y JPA, el problema es que no tengo instalado en mi netbeans (8.2) el plugin para desarrollo web, al querer instalarlo me da un warning en la conexión del proxy el cual tengo desactivado y me impide descargar plugins... he visto en  [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140566/netbeans-not-able-to-connect-to-internet) y parece ser un problema de protocolo ip, he modificado desde el cmd : setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true pero  a mi no me ha funcionado y sigo sin poder descargarme ningún plugin...alguien ha podido solucionar esto?

dejo capturas:
[image: Netbeans]
[image: descarga]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans llevaba unos años en transición de Oracle a Apache Software Foundation mientras se implementaban todas las funcionalidades en el nuevo desarrollo, esa transición ya se ha finalizado y Oracle ha dado de baja todos los repositorios y binarios de NetBeans 8.2, la única opción es migrar a la nueva versión de NetBeans 12.3  `https://netbeans.apache.org/` que es la nueva línea de desarrollo sobre la que continuara el proyecto.